# $3^3$ factorial design

Tags: anova, interpretation, experiment-design, inference, causality

Suppose in a $3^3$ factorial design, factor *A* has three levels. We want to test the significance of *A* and after setting hypothesis $$H_0:\alpha_i=0 \quad\text{for}\quad i=1,2,3 \quad\text{Vs.}\quad H_1:\alpha_i\ne 0 \quad\text{(Is that correct $H_1$ setting?) }$$  performing an ANOVA test, we conclude that "there is significant effect of factor *A*."

What does it mean? is there variation among different levels of factor *A*?

Is that $2^3$ factorial design one way ANOVA (Because there is no blocking) or two way ANOVA (Because there is two treatment effects)?

Comment: I don't think that factor A can have three levels in a $2^{3}$ design (unless one of its levels was omitted).  See https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat503/node/34

Comment: Also, if this is a homework problem, please tag the question with [self-study].

Comment: @AndrewM oh, this would be $3^3$ factorial design.